# How to alter and add 'id' coloumn in my view mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have view on mysql, but I do not have id coloumn with AI, how can ı sort it out. I tried this but did not work

```
ALTER view `user_address_view` add `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: You can't add a column like that to a view... Doesn't the base table(s) have any primary key?

Comment: yeah my base table has primary key but I need to do  JPA entity with this view table

Comment: You can use a CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW to replace your current view and include the column that you would like to add in the SELECT clause.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing views and tables.  When you modify a view, you need to provide the query that is to be executed.

You can do this in MySQL 8.0 as:

```
create view v as
    select row_number() over (order by ?) as id, t.*
    from t;
```

You can do this in a query as:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, t.*
from t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params;
```

Unfortunately, MySQL does not allow variables in views, so there is not an efficient way to do this in a view.